# React / Unit Test (Jest) click method with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-test-renderer

So I got a little issue I am stumped with...

I have a `Link` component which will either go to a specific route via a `to` prop, if a certain condition is met. If that condition is not met, that link, when clicked, will do something else (launch a custom modal, in my case).

I have a class method which is bound to an `onClick` handler on my `Link` component

```js
// Card.jsx

import Link from 'components/Link';

...

static props = {
  condition: PropTypes.bool
};

constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    showModal: false
  };
}

...

goToUrlOrLaunchModal() {
  return (
    <Link
      to="www.google.com"
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    />
  );
}


... 


handleClick(e) {
  const { condition } = this.props;

  if (!condition) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
  }
}
```

My issue is with unit testing. I have a unit test for clicking the link when `condition` is `false`

```js
// Card.test.js

...

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

...

const event = {
  preventDefault: jest.fn()
};

const component = renderer.create(<Card>).getInstance();

instance.handleClick(event);
expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(instance.state.showModal).toBe(true);
```

Where I am getting lost is testing the other side - when `condition` is `true`, I do not need to call `preventDefault` or perform any logic after that. I do not need anything in `handleClick` to fire. The only logic in `handleClick` is for when `condition` is false.

The logic to go to the route when clicking the `Link` component is fine, it's just the unit test for when `condition` is `true`.

I need to test that `preventDefault` has not been called, and that `instance.state.showModal` is to be `true`, but I am stumped. Here is what I keep thinking it has to be, but cannot get past it...

```js
const event = {
  preventDefault: jest.fn()
};

expect(instance.handleManageClick).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(event.preventDefault).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(instance.state.showModal).toBe(false);
```

If anyone has some guidance, would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I am not familiar with `react-test-renderer`, because I use `jest`, but the traditional way to observe function calls is with spies. Have you tried using them yet?

Comment: I tried to do something like `const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleManageClick');`
and then run `expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();`, and the test passed, but according to another developer reviewing my pull request, that is not necessary, and the `handleClick` method just needs to be called, which makes zero sense to me, because the whole point is not to call `event.preventDefault`, and if `handleClick` is called without an `event` argument passed to it, it just errors saying that `event.preventDefault` is not a function, if that makes sense.

But yes, I tried spies...

Comment: I completely disagree with your colleague. What is the purpose of testing a click handler if you are not testing implementation details? If I decide to remove all inner content of `handleManageClick` and replace it with just: `console.log('yes this totally should pass the test'), should the test still pass? Peer review comments are not word of law. A healthy work environment should allow discussion on any respectful disagreements

Comment: I completely disagree with him as well, and there is no other correct way which makes sense, and especially with your argument, I know this to be true. Thanks for your help, I'm good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the answer, thanks to the help of [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385889/andrew) who commented on the initial post.

Here is what I did:

```js
// Card.test.js

const event = {
  preventDefault: jest.fn()
};

const component = renderer.create(<Card>).getInstance();

const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleManageClick');

expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(event.preventDefault).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(instance.state.showModal).toBe(false);
```

Thanks for your help!